# InputStream wrong filesize

Tags: java, android

I try to implement a Progressbar during an Upload. A picture (207 byte) is uploaded to a FTP Server. 
The problem is, that the class ProgressInputStream doesn´t print the correct progress size in the console.
This is how I start the upload:

```
File file = new File(path);

String firstRemoteFile = "" + file.getName() + IMEI;
         InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        System.out.println("Start uploading first file"+file.length());


        ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream("test",inputStream, file.length());

    boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, progressInput);
```

ProgressInputStream

```
public class ProgressInputStream extends InputStream {
private final long size;
public long progress;
private long lastUpdate = 0;
private final InputStream inputStream;
private final String name;
private boolean closed = false;

public ProgressInputStream(String name, InputStream inputStream, long size) {
this.size = size;
this.inputStream = inputStream;
this.name = name;
}

public ProgressInputStream(String name, FileContent content)
throws FileSystemException {
this.size = content.getSize();
this.name = name;
this.inputStream = content.getInputStream();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
super.close();
if (closed) throw new IOException("already closed");
closed = true;
}

@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
int count = inputStream.read();
if (count > 0)
    progress += count;
lastUpdate = maybeUpdateDisplay(name, progress, lastUpdate, size);
return count;
 }
@Override
  public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
int count = inputStream.read(b, off, len);
if (count > 0)
    progress += count;
lastUpdate = maybeUpdateDisplay(name, progress, lastUpdate, size);
System.out.println("count"+count+"size"+size);
return count;

}


static long maybeUpdateDisplay(String name, long progress, long lastUpdate, long size)   {

System.out.println("name "+ name+"  progress "+ progress+" lastUpdate "+ lastUpdate+"     "+ "sie "+ size);
return lastUpdate;
}}
```

Logcat

```
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 13913 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14093 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14093 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14093 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14093 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14337 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14337 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14567 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14567 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14687 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14770 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14770 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14778 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14778 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14778 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14778 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14837 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14837 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
09-17 20:03:39.828: I/System.out(11346): name test  progress 14837 lastUpdate 0 sie 207
```

I dont know why the progress is this high. At the end progress should be 207.

I am grateful for any advice (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ProgressInputStream  like this:

```
public class ProgressInputStream extends InputStream {

public ProgressInputStream(String name, InputStream inputStream, long size) {
this.size = size;
this.inputStream = inputStream;
this.name = name;
 }

public ProgressInputStream(String name, FileContent content)
throws FileSystemException {
this.size = content.getSize();
this.name = name;
this.inputStream = content.getInputStream();
 }

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
super.close();
if (closed) throw new IOException("already closed");
closed = true;
 }

@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
int count = inputStream.read();

    progress ++;
lastUpdate = maybeUpdateDisplay(name, progress, lastUpdate, size);

 return count;
}
/*@Override
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
int count = inputStream.read(b, off, len);

progress ++;
lastUpdate = maybeUpdateDisplay(name, progress, lastUpdate, size);
System.out.println("count"+count+"size"+size);

return count;

}*/


static long maybeUpdateDisplay(String name, long progress, long lastUpdate, long size)     {
  /* if (Config.isInUnitTests()) return lastUpdate;
  if (size < B_IN_MB/10) return lastUpdate;
  if (progress - lastUpdate > 1024 * 10) {
    lastUpdate = progress;
    int hashes = (int) (((double)progress / (double)size) * 40);
    if (hashes > 40) hashes = 40;
    String bar = StringUtils.repeat("#",
            hashes);
    bar = StringUtils.rightPad(bar, 40);
    System.out.format("%s [%s] %.2fMB/%.2fMB\r",
            name, bar, progress / B_IN_MB, size / B_IN_MB);
    System.out.flush();
  }*/


 System.out.println("name "+ name+"  progress "+ progress+" lastUpdate "+ lastUpdate+"      "+ "sie "+ size);
return lastUpdate;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
progress += count;
```

to

```
progress++;
```

EDIT

Check here

```
Int count = inputStream.read(b, off, len);
```

Does count == the full length of your file ?

Comment: it nearly worked, but now it prints out: progress:149 size:207 , same with bigger file, it doesnt count the last bytes, why?

Comment: Edited with proposition